# Codeigniter get number of rows of complex query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, paging

I have a complex query with multiple inner joins in it. The query is written in pure SQL. I don't want to convert it to Active Record. For paging, I need to know the total number of rows that query will return but I don't want to execute it. I tried:

```
$this->db->count_all_results($query);
```

but it returns nothing. Is there any other way to get count of rows from a complex query written in SQL ?

Here is the query:

```
SELECT o.id, o.heading, o.description, p.product_name, s.company_name
            FROM ci_offer o 
            INNER JOIN ci_products p ON o.product_id = p.id
            INNER JOIN ci_suppliers s ON p.supplier_id = s.id
            ORDER BY o.modified DESC
```

Comment: does your query have a `group by` clause?

Comment: no it doesn't. It does have ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Can you provide us your query?

Comment: I can't provide it since providing it will not help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use count_all_results you'll need to use ActiveRecord.

But you can also replace the columns in the SELECT clause with

```
COUNT(1) AS total
```

Comment: This looks like a viable solution. I will definitely try it.

Answer (score 1):

`count_all_results()` Permits you to determine the number of rows **in a particular Active Record query**!

you are going to need to run the query and to let mysql give you number of records that the query returns as result. if you need only the number of resulting rows, try the following:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM ci_offer o 
INNER JOIN ci_products p ON o.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN ci_suppliers s ON p.supplier_id = s.id
ORDER BY o.modified DESC
```

Comment: Yes thats what the accepted answer says as well. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda strange expectation :) I don't think even MySQL can predict the number of result rows of particular query without executing it, not to mention the PHP framework.

What you can try is to use either SQL transaction and then rollback or maybe EXPLAIN.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
$count = $query->num_rows();
```

Instead of :

```
$count = $this->db->count_all_results($query);
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Im Using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS to get total count.

```
$this->db->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ci_offer.id', false);
$this->db->select('FOUND_ROWS() as total_rows', false);
$query = $this->db->get();
$total = $query->row_array();
$list_array['total'] = $total['total_rows'];
```